# Classification - get exact label value to check how close to another class (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, classification, text-classification, naivebayes

I am doing text classification in python with 3 alghoritms: kNN, Naive Bayes and SVM. I have 3 classes - easy, medium and hard. The accuracy is quite fine. Is there a way to check for new text its exact value? After label encoding 0 is easy, 1 is medium and 2 is hard. So base on new text for example it is classified as medium but I want to know how close it was to easy/hard. Some of my code snippets:

```
Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = model_selection.train_test_split(
    df['tokens'], df['class'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

Encoder = LabelEncoder()
Train_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Train_Y)
Test_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y)

Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=35)
Tfidf_vect.fit([' '.join(arr) for arr in df['tokens']])
Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform([' '.join(arr) for arr in Train_X])
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform([' '.join(arr) for arr in Test_X])
Naive = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
Naive.fit(Train_X_Tfidf, Train_Y)
predictions_NB = Naive.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)
print(round(accuracy_score(predictions_NB, Test_Y)*100, 2))
```

Now when I use Naive.predict() I get 0, 1 or 2. Is there a way to get the EXACT value for example 0,5897237489 which is 1 but I see that it is closer to 0 than 2

Comment: You could look at the predict_proba() functions, which return probability estimates for each class. You could use this to determine the confidence of your match

Comment: @IgnacyDebicki this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Does it have some mathematical name? Or any resource I could read about it how it works and what it counts there so I don't just use it but understand as well?

Comment: It will vary between the classifiers used. For Naive Bayes, the sklearn library uses the exponent of the log probability, which is explained here: http://www.cs.rhodes.edu/~kirlinp/courses/ai/f18/projects/proj3/naive-bayes-log-probs.pdf